# Method throws exception with message "Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only"

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

When I call **POST** method it throws exception with message *"Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only"*. I have tried to change transaction strategies. Changed propagation levels, rollback(rollbackFor, rollbackForClassName) cases. But I could not find a solution.

I have **entity**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORGANIZATION")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Organization extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ORGANIZATION_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "ORGANIZATION_ID_SEQ", name = "ORGANIZATION_ID", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "MANAGER_FULL_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String managerFullName;

    @Column(name = "IIN", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String iin;

    @Column(name = "IBAN", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String iban;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "TEL_NUMBER", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String telNumber;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "CONFIRMATION_STATUS")
    private OrganizationConfirmationStatus confirmationStatus = OrganizationConfirmationStatus.NEW;

    @Column(name = "CONFIRMED_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime confirmedDate;

    @Column(name = "CONFIRMED_BY")
    private String confirmedBy;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "ORGANIZATION_USER_FK"))
    @JsonManagedReference
    private SecUser user;

    @Column(name = "COMPANY_NAME")
    private String companyName;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "INSTAGRAM_LINK")
    private String instagramLink;

    @Column(name = "SITE_LINK")
    private String siteLink;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_CATEGORY_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "ORGANIZATION_COMPANY_CATEGORY_FK"))
    @JsonManagedReference
    private CompanyCategory companyCategory;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "ORGANIZATION_PICS",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ORGANIZATION_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "ORGANIZATION_PICS_ORGANIZATION_FK")),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FILE_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "ORGANIZATION_PICS_FILE_FK")))
    private List<SysFile> pics;

    @Column(name = "REJECT_MESSAGE")
    private String rejectMessage;

    public void addPic(SysFile pic){
        getPics().add(pic);
    }

    public void deletePic(SysFile pic){
        if(!getPics().isEmpty()){
            getPics().remove(pic);
        }
    }

    public void deletePics(List<SysFile> pics){
        if(!getPics().isEmpty()){
            this.getPics().removeAll(pics);
        }
    }

}
```

And **repository**:

```
@Repository
public interface OrgRepo extends JpaRepository<Organization, Long> {
}
```

And **service**:

```
public interface OrgService {
    Organization createOrg(OrganizationCreateFilter filter);
}
```

And **implementation**:

```
@Service
public class OrgServiceImpl implements OrgService {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyCategoryService companyCategoryService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    private OrgRepo repo;

    @Override
    public Organization createOrg(OrganizationCreateFilter filter) {
        SecUser user = userService.getOne(filter.getUserId());
        CompanyCategory companyCategory = companyCategoryService.getOne(filter.getCompanyCategoryId());

        Organization organization = new Organization();
        organization.setUser(user);
        organization.setConfirmationStatus(OrganizationConfirmationStatus.CONFIRMED);
        organization.setEmail(filter.getEmail());
        organization.setIban(filter.getIban());
        organization.setName(filter.getName());
        organization.setManagerFullName(filter.getManagerFullName());
        organization.setTelNumber(filter.getTelNumber());
        organization.setIin(filter.getIin());
        organization.setCompanyCategory(companyCategory);
        organization.setCompanyName(filter.getCompanyName());
        organization.setAddress(filter.getAddress());
        organization.setDescription(filter.getDescription());
        organization.setSiteLink(filter.getSiteLink());
        organization.setInstagramLink(filter.getInstagramLink());
        return repo.save(organization);
    }
}
```

And **controller**:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin/orgs")
public class AdminOrgRest {

    @Autowired
    private OrgService orgService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> addOne(@Valid @RequestBody OrganizationCreateFilter filter) {
        try{
            orgService.createOrg(filter);
            return ResponseModel.successPure();
        } catch (Exception e){
            return ResponseModel.error(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:752)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at kz.open.sankaz.service.impl.OrganizationServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a4e6144e.createOrg(<generated>)
    at kz.open.sankaz.rest.admin.AdminOrgRest.addOne(AdminOrgRest.java:74)
    at kz.open.sankaz.rest.admin.AdminOrgRest$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ba9f907d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at kz.open.sankaz.rest.admin.AdminOrgRest$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$595b04e5.addOne(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthorizationFilter.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at kz.open.sankaz.filter.CustomAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(CustomAuthorizationFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

But other **POST** and **PUT** methods are not throwing the same exception. Please, help!

Comment: Your service should be `@Transactional`, I don't see it. Secondly use `findOne` instead of `getOne`.

Comment: I added @Transactional, but i did not help. Changed to findOne, also did not helped.

Comment: Something must be triggering the rollback. Not sure what, your controller you have here wouldn't even work as it wouldn't get anything injected. So is this your actual code or a dumbed down version of it?

Comment: It is dumbed down version. Sorry, I missed the line with @Autowired there in conroller.

Comment: Then I'm not going to even try to start to answer this question. It is a dumbed down version, so a version which probably doesn't even have the issue. Please use actual code or code that we can run to actually see the issue.